# How to add API level into NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, c++builder, android-api-levels

IDE asks me for android-14 for NDK. How could I get it ?
[image]

I have r18b version of NDK.
Here is what I have in platforms directory:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This **android-14** is just an example. You can choose the best platfrom level that is good for your project. RAD Studio v10.3 [supports](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development) Android platforms 21 and higher. If you choose e.g. **android-24**, your APK will not run reliably on devices with Lollipop or Marshmellow, but such choice [lets you use more APIs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis#a24) (e.g. Native cmaera2).

Comment: Why you're mentioning android-24, but not android-28 ?

Comment: The only reason was that 24 was highlighted on the screenshot ;)

Answer (score 0):

**android-14** was removed since ndk r18b, You can download an older version of NDK, e.g. android-ndk-r16b from here:https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases, unzip it and you will see **android-14** available inside `/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/`.

About how to decide the proper android platform for your NDK build, you can check my recent answer to another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53477672/8034839